# Kiel diri "stop-motion animation" esperante?

Tags: translation

Mi pensis "bildo-per-bildo animacio", sed ĝi estas uomete longa. Ĉu ĝi eĉ ĝustas?

Comment: Oni povus inventi la terminon "bildaran animacion" tamen ĉu "haltmova animacio" ne same taŭgas kaj estas pli rekonebla (almenaŭ en la anglalingva mondo), Rigardu la tradukojn en aliaj lingvoj, kiel en la vikipedio. "Stop motion" estas sufiĉe ofte netradukita.

Answer (score 7):

*Per* signifas *uzanta*, do via sugesto devus esti *foto-post-fota animacio*, ĉar la vorto *bildo* povus aludi desegnaĵojn samkiel fotojn. *Stop-motion* estas animacio de senmovaj pupoj per movetoj inter fotoj. Mi sugestas ***interfota animacio*** aŭ ***pupa animacio***.

Vikipedio nur donas ***halto-movo***, rektan tradukon de la angla.

Answer (score 4):

Mi dirus *bildpostbild-filmado* aŭ *unuopbilda filmado*.

Answer (score 4):

We discussed this question in the *supera nivelo* class at NASK this year. The actual question raised had to do with the term *animacio* itself and whether it should be considered an anglicism.

The short answer is that many languages do use the term (which has nothing to do with *animo*) with the English meaning (having borrowed it from English) and so, by the 15th rule, *animacio* certainly is a part of Esperanto - but that indigenous Esperanto alternatives exist, such as *desegnofilmo*.

We also discussed that there are many kinds of animation - and given the amount of overlap between different methods, and the way these methods change with technology, it's difficult to make suggestions that will stand the test of time. With that in mind, it's important to describe the method in any suggestion made.

All historic methods of animation involve putting one photo after another - whether these are photos of drawings or of solid objects - so the term would have to distinguish stop motion from these other types. I've never found the term "stop motion" overly transparent, so I would hesitate to use a direct translation.

So, depending on what is being animated, I might say **argil-figura film(ad)o** or **pupo-animacio**.